# April fools - PsExec (PsTools)

Tags: powershell, connection, psexec

I need to execute a command on every windows computer for an April fools joke, but I can't get PsExec to work without authentication

Here is my command: `C:\PsTools\psexec \\192.168.1.6 -accepteula -nobanner powershell -Command "Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework; [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Happy April Fools!!!')"`

and here is my output:

```
Couldn't access 192.168.1.6:
The user name or password is incorrect.
```

I expected it to work and show the popup on the other computer, but it just didn't. Can someone help me, because I need to pull this off soon, and if there are other alternatives to PsExec, can you share them?

P.S. I don't want the client to have to do anything or the network admins to do anything